# How to handle too long Gherkin scenario lines?

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I have some scenarios with too many parameters and most of the parameters causes the variation of scenarios. Therefore, I need to include parameter details in scenario name to give insight about the scenario. However, this causes too long Scenario lines.

For Example:

```
Scenario: Create list for Today's unique stuff of 'X' item with multiple string attribute values and 'distinct count' aggregation
    Given I create a 'Create List' request and name as 'New List'
    When I add 'X' item to 'Create List' request
    And I add item attribute to current list query on list preview request
      | attribute | operator | values  |
      | id        | EXMATCH  | id1,id2 |
    And I add list aggregation to current list query on 'Create List' request
      | aggField | aggType        |
      | stuff     | DISTINCT_COUNT |
    And I send request to 'Create List' request date as 'TODAY'
    Then 'success' parameter in response should be true
    And received list name should be equal to created list name
    And received list queries in 'Create List' response should be equal to created list queries
```

Another Scenario:

```
Scenario: Create list for Today's unique stuff of 'X' item with multiple integer attribute values and 'sum' aggregation
```

Or:

```
Scenario: Create list for Today's unique stuff of 'X' item with multiple integer attribute values, 'sum' aggregation and <some other parameter related conditions which causes too long scenario name>
```

This can go on and on according to the number of different parameters who effects the scenario.
I have a feeling like there must be best practices writing clearer and shorter scenario names. Are there any?
How should I handle these long scenario names? Or, can I find easer/shorter way of express the content of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber allows you to use natural language (as opposed to a programming language) to write your scenarios. You can use all the tools of natural language to simplify your scenarios.

The two most powerful tools to simplify are

- abstraction
- naming

These tools work hand in hand. With abstraction you take something with alot of details and abstract it into something simpler that removes the details. You use naming to give this new thing a name. If your name is good you can know talk about your complex thing using your new simple term and no longer have to talk about the details.

To make you scenarios simpler you need to abstract, remove the details, and give things good names. The way to do this is to read your scenario and differentiate between WHAT you are doing and HOW you are doing it. Then have your scenarios focus on only saying WHAT they are doing and not saying anything about HOW they are doing it.

One additional tool when thinking about WHAT something is doing is to also think about WHY someone is doing the thing. So lets have a look at your scenario and formulate a few questions.

We do this all the time in computing. Every time we write a method/function we are abstracting and naming. We do this even more often in real life. When you order a coffee you don't say

> "I'd like a double expresso in a warmed cup  with 3oz of milk wet
> foamed at 60C poured with a swan pattern"

You say

> "I'd like a flat white"

And of course a double expresso is just another abstraction for a set of instructions that talks about water temperature, number of grammes of coffee, grind settings (extra fine), pressure of water etc. etc.

By using abstraction and naming we can talk eloquently about coffee with all its complexity without mentioning any of the details.

So what is the 'flat white' or 'double expresso' for your scenario?

Your scenario seems to be about creating some sort of a list.

- WHAT sort of list is this?
- WHY are you creating it?
- WHAT will people use this list for?
- WHY will people find this list useful?

Once you have asked and answered these questions you can start thinking about how to simplify. When you answer these questions, use the answers to

- name your feature
- describe your feature
- write a preamble for your feature (the bit between Feature and the first Scenario)
- write you Scenario titles

You shouldn't start writing a scenario until you have all of this done, and have a Feature that tells you WHAT your scenarios are going to be about and WHY its important for you to do these things.

You also talk about the parameters you are adding causing a variation in the scenarios. So for each parameter you are adding you should be asking

- WHAT sort of variation does this parameter cause?
- WHY is this variation important? Is it important enough to have its own scenario?

Again think about sets of parameters creating named things like a mocha, cortado or latte.

When you have answered these questions you can remove the parameters from your scenarios. Each set of parameters that creates a variation. For each variation you can remove the parameters by abstracting and giving a name to the variation

If you apply this approach and answer these questions then you transform your scenarios into something much simpler